# Laravel 5 Hide Data Passed From Controller to View Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, laravel

In my app I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to get events from my facebook pages. I'm passing the page access tokens from my controller to the Javascript code in my view. However, when I View Source on my page, I can see the access tokens, so anyone determined can post anything to my facebook pages.

Is there any way to add some security to this so that people cannot see the token access codes if they View Source?

P.S.: I know I could use the Facebook PHP SDK to solve this, but I'm more accustomed to the JS SDK, and I would like to make it work this way if possible.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You _must_ do this server-side.

Comment: I'm sure the client side JS facebook SDK would have a way to be used without exposing sensitive information. It would be useless otherwise.

Comment: @apokryfos I can't find anything that would suggest that

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to minimy the JS code before deploying to the server, no?

Comment: No. Minification is not encryption. Are you sure the JS SDK needs access tokens to in the code to work? It's client side so it should work with the browser cookies.

Comment: Yes, it needs the access tokens to get the events from the facebook pages. Even if I put the access tokens in cookies, it still not very secure I think..

Comment: This is not the best solution but you can get your Access Token via the separate call from your server and assign token to the variable. Anyway anyone can access your token from your code using the breakpoint and watch in the right place. So I suggest using server side SDK.